# How to set UncaughtExceptionHandler for a thread group

Tags: java, multithreading, threadgroup

Suppose I have 5 threads belonging to a thread group named "Fruits-group".

How can I assign `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to all threads of `Fruits-group` at one go?

I know we can define a global `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for all threads. 
What I am looking for is assigning a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to an entire thread-group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Subclass the `ThreadGroup` and override the `uncaughtException()` method.

A [`ThreadGroup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) *is* an [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html), implementing the [`uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException-java.lang.Thread-java.lang.Throwable-) method:

> Called by the Java Virtual Machine when a thread in this thread group stops because of an uncaught exception, and the thread does not have a specific Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler installed.
>
> The `uncaughtException` method of `ThreadGroup` does the following:
>
> - If this thread group has a parent thread group, the `uncaughtException` method of that parent is called with the same two arguments.
> - Otherwise, this method checks to see if there is a default uncaught exception handler installed, and if so, its `uncaughtException` method is called with the same two arguments.
> - Otherwise, this method determines if the `Throwable` argument is an instance of `ThreadDeath`. If so, nothing special is done. Otherwise, a message containing the thread's name, as returned from the thread's `getName` method, and a stack backtrace, using the `Throwable`'s `printStackTrace` method, is printed to the standard error stream.
>
> **Applications can override this method in subclasses of `ThreadGroup` to provide alternative handling of uncaught exceptions.**

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to be able to *set* an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for the `ThreadGroup`, you can create a delegating subclass:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingThreadGroup extends ThreadGroup {
    private UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler;
    
    public ExceptionHandlingThreadGroup(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public ExceptionHandlingThreadGroup(ThreadGroup parent, String name) {
        super(parent, name);
    }
    
    public UncaughtExceptionHandler getUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return this.uncaughtExceptionHandler;
    }
    public void setUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler) {
        this.uncaughtExceptionHandler = uncaughtExceptionHandler;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        if (this.uncaughtExceptionHandler != null)
            this.uncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);
        else
            super.uncaughtException(t, e);
    }
}
```

In general, though, it would likely be better to just *implement* the exception handling logic directly in the subclass, but this way, you can use an existing `UncaughtExceptionHandler` implementation.

Comment: `public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) `.  I understand we have to pass an instance of UncaughtExceptionHandler in the second argument,  but which thread instance we should pass in the first parameter: `any, or the current thread`

Comment: @PrakashPandey What do you mean? You implement the `uncaughtException()` method in a subclass of `ThreadGroup`, and the JVM will call it. You don't call it. If you want your subclass to take a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and store it in a field of your subclass, and forward the call from the subclass `uncaughtException()` implementation to the given `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, you'd pass on the two parameter values.